# Answer posted to question after question was put on hold

Tags: bug, closed-questions

I've put a [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345592/magic-keyboard-issues-at-startup) on hold, nevertheless a user was able to post an answer later on:

[image]

Seems like a bug to me, but maybe I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indeed possible to answer a question which is put on hold, if you're still on the question page. You'll get a banner "this question is now put on-hold" and this will disable the 'Submit' button, but it's relatively easy to re-enable it via the developer tools of the browser. The server will still accept new answers for a few hours or so.

See also [this Q&A on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4683/295232).

Comment: Thanks. So much for being too lazy to look on Meta.SE first...